# Sufficient condition for holomorphic function being constant

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ be an holomorphic function.
> Furthermore, suppose that:
> \begin{align*}
> \exists \ (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}:\quad a\operatorname{Re}(f) + b\operatorname{Im}(f) \text{ is constant}. 
> \end{align*}
> Show that $f$ is constant.

By the hypothesis above, we can arrive at the following linear system:
\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
  a\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}+b\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}=0
\\[2pt]
  a\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}+b\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}=0
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}

As $(a,b)\neq (0,0)$, then:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}-\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}} &= 0    \\
\Bigl(\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}\Bigr)^2 + \Bigl(\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}\Bigr)^2 &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
So, $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}$=$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}=0$ and similarly, $\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}$=$\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}=0$, then $f$ is constant.
Is this a valid argument? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should be correct.

One other solution would be to observe that if $\text{Re}(f)$ is constant then $f$ is constant.

With this observe the following: it is $a\text{Re}(f)+b\text{Im}(f) = \text{Re}(\bar w f)$ with $w := a + bi\neq 0$. So, if $a\text{Re}(f)+b\text{Im}(f)$ is constant then $\text{Re}(\bar w f)$ is constant, so $\bar w f$ is constant and therefore $f$ is constant (since $w \neq 0$).